# Reading a file in Python, contents do not get displayed

Tags: python-2.7, io

I am have simple function *read* written in a file *processFile.py* which opens a file, reads the contents and displays it.
However i do not see the contents being printed.

```
def read:
    fileObj = open("file.txt","r")
    lines   =  fileObj.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print line,
    fileObj.close()
```

When i run this as below

```
$python processFile.py
>> nothing gets displayed and the prompt returns
```

Comment: Do you ever actually *call* `read()`? Also, it should be `def read():` (note parentheses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def read():
    fileObj = open("file.txt","r")
    lines   =  fileObj.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print line,
    fileObj.close()

read()
```

Your two issues are that you don't define your function correctly (forgot the parenthesis) and that you never call it.